# Is there any way I can compare message arguments to a .json file

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have this code:

```
const Command = require("../Structures/Command.js");
const { menu } = require("../data/menu.json");

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "order",
    description: "Make an order",

    async run(message, args, client){
        args.toString().toLowerCase();
            switch(args[1]){
            case menu[1]:
                message.reply(`accepted your order for ${menu[1]}!`);
                break;
            case menu[0]:
                message.reply(`accepted your order for ${menu[0]}`);
                break;
            case menu[2]:
                    message.reply(`accepted your order for a ${menu[2]}`);
                    break;
            default:
                message.reply(`sorry, we either don't serve that here, or you didn't say what you want to order`);
            }
    }
    })
```

And what I want it to do:

- Check args
- Compare if args are any of the menu elements
- Give an answer based on the element 
  Like:

```
if(args == menu){
    message.reply(`accepted your order for ${menu[args]}!`);
}
```

menu.json:

```
{
    "menu": ["coffee", "donut", "tea"]
}
```

I know it sounds a little bit confusing, but I hope you are able to help.

Comment: Please show an example of what `args` is. Presumably `menu` is `["coffee", "donut", "tea"]`.

Comment: If I write "{prefix} order donut" here is what I get: [ 'order', 'donut' ]

Comment: I now check like this "if(args[1].includes(menu))" and it's a step in the right direction because it tells me that it doesn't serve the item

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum, where we put "[SOLVED]" in the title and the solution in the question. It's a question and answer site. If you solved it, answer the question with your solution. Accept (and possibly upvote) the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that somethin like this gonna work!

```js
var menu = ["coffee", "donut", "tea"];
var args = "Tea";

if(menu.includes(args.toLowerCase())) {
  console.log("Order accept " + menu[menu.indexOf(args.toLowerCase())]);
}else {
  console.log("Product not found");
}
```

Comment: (node:6900) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: args.toLowerCase is not a function

Comment: [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is a more modern way of writing `indexOf(...) != -1`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey i'm in a phone and just giving a example, this is not final code! but i've edited

Comment: @nFl1p in your case use args[1] because the args variable is a array in your code.

Comment: @naxsi args.toLowerCase is still not a function(i set args to args[1])

Comment: alright it worked